# Problems (wrong scale, aspect ratio) while rendering MTKTexture to MTKView after applying compute shaders

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, metal, metalkit

I am trying to process video frames from the camera using compute metal shaders and display it to the user. The problem is with displaying the modified frames. The output contains stacked copies of the processed frame with some of them clipped and they don't fill the screen completely.

P.S I am new to both iOS and metal

So far, I have identified variables that control this:
1. Number of Thread groups launched
2. MTKView's drawable size
3. sampling id in the metal shader

I have played around with these with no good result.

Below are the code and my output

The function that sets up the MTKView

```
func initMetalView() {

        metalView = MTKView(frame: view.frame, device: metalDevice)

        metalView.delegate = self
        metalView.framebufferOnly = false
        metalView.colorPixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
        metalView.autoResizeDrawable = false
        metalView.drawableSize = CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080)
        metalView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(Float.pi),0.0,1.0,0.0)

        view.insertSubview(metalView, at: 0)

    }
```

The AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate used to convert CMSampleBuffer to MTLTexture

```
extension ViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        // sample buffer -> image buffer -> CoreVideo metal texture -> MTL texture

        guard let cvImageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            else { fatalError("can't get image buffer") }

        var textureCache: CVMetalTextureCache?

        guard CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, nil, metalDevice, nil, &textureCache) == kCVReturnSuccess else { fatalError("cant create texture cache") }

        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvImageBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvImageBuffer)

        var imageTexture: CVMetalTexture?
        let result = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache!, cvImageBuffer, nil, MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm, width, height, 0, &imageTexture)

        guard let unwrappedImageTexture = imageTexture,
            result == kCVReturnSuccess
            else { fatalError("failed to create texture from image") }

        inputTexture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(unwrappedImageTexture)

    }
}
```

The MTKViewDelegate used to apply the shader on `inputTexture` and display the `outputTexture` to `metalView`

```
extension ViewController: MTKViewDelegate {

    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {

    }

    func draw(in view: MTKView) {

        guard let inputTexture = inputTexture,
            let commandQueue = commandQueue,
            let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(),
            let encoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder(),
            let pipelineState = pipelineState
        else { return }

        encoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)

        encoder.setTextures([metalView.currentDrawable!.texture, inputTexture], range: 0..<2)

        encoder.dispatchThreadgroups(MTLSizeMake(inputTexture.width/16, inputTexture.height/16, 1), threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerBlock)
        // inputTexture w:1920, h:1080

        encoder.endEncoding()

        commandBuffer.present(metalView.currentDrawable!)
        commandBuffer.commit()

    }
}
```

The metal compute shader

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void blacky (texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[texture(0)]],
                   texture2d<float, access::read> inTexture [[texture(1)]],
                   uint2 id [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {

    uint2 flipped_id = uint2(id.y, id.x);
    float3 val = inTexture.read(flipped_id).rgb;
    float g = (val.r + val.g + val.b)/3.0;
    float4 out = float4(g, g, g, 1);
    outTexture.write(out.rgba, id);

}
```

You can see the current output here: https://i.imgur.com/hVDox3U

Comment: Are the view dimensions you are rendering into exactly the same as the dimensions as the input texture? If not, then you would want to scale the texture to fit the view with a fragment based shader to implement the rescaling.

Comment: @MoDJ No the view dimensions and the input texture are not the same. The view dimensions are 1334x750 whereas the texture is 1920x1080. I do understand the need to scale. But since I am using a compute shader wouldn't it be an added overhead to pass it through a fragment shader again. Is it possible to scale the texture within a compute shader or do image processing in a fragment shader, so that effectively the texture is acted upon by only one shader function? thanks.

Comment: In general, the rescale step is quite expensive, but there is no way around it. But you might be able to avoid additional processing by first doing the rescale operation in a fragment shader and then applying a grayscale conversion before outputting the pixel value in the frag shader.